# STAX XMLStreamWriter doesn't write with small files

Tags: java, xml, stax

I have a little program using **STAX** which copy the content of a XML file to another.
By the way, I discovered an enigmatic problem with **XMLStreamWriter**.

When I try to write many elements, the writing works. But when I try to write few elements, it doesn't works (the file is empty).

For example, this code works (3000 elements):

```
    XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamWriter writer = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("toto.xml"));

    writer.writeStartDocument();
    for(int i = 0; i < 3000; ++i) {
        writer.writeStartElement("toto");
        writer.writeEndElement();
    }
    writer.writeEndDocument();
```

And this code doesn't work (50 elements):

```
    XMLOutputFactory outputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamWriter writer = outputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("toto.xml"));

    writer.writeStartDocument();
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        writer.writeStartElement("toto");
        writer.writeEndElement();
    }
    writer.writeEndDocument();
```

Have you any idea ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
writer.close();
```

;) Typical behaviour.

Comment: I missed it. Thank you a lot.
writer.flush() can be a solution too, but close() seems more clean.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this too today, but `writer.flush()` didn't work, only `writer.close()` o_o